# code structure for streamWrite

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a much better way for me to streamWrite without needing to repeat the code for every button I press? Below is an example I am working on where one button does it's own thing and writes accordingly to vowels and the other does the same thing except it writes accordingly for no alpha characters:

```
        private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string wholeText = "";
            string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Second_File) == true)
            {

                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Second_File);

                string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
                copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());
                wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + copyText;

                objWriter.Write(wholeText);
                richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
                objWriter.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No file named " + Second_File);
            }
        }

private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string wholeText = "";
            string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Second_File) == true)
            {

                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Second_File);

                string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
                string addSpace = "";
                copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

                objWriter.Write(wholeText);
                richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
                objWriter.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No file named " + Second_File);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it windows form ?

Comment: Yes it is, I will include the tag

Comment: As an aside, don't do "if(something == true)", just do "if (something)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not doing it this way?

```
private void Write(string file, string text)
{
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            objWriter.Write(text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file named " + file);
    }
}

private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string wholeText = "";
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;

    string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
    string addSpace = "";
    copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

    wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + copyText;

    Write(Second_File, wholeText); // same for the second button

    richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a common function that will take care of writing the contents to the file and updating the second textbox:

```
private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
    string addSpace = "";
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);
    WriteToFile(Second_File, wholeText);
}

private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

    string wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + copyText;
    WriteToFile(Second_File, wholeText);
}

private void WriteToFile(string filename, string contents)
{
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
        richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file named " + filename);
    }
}
```